# Converting a Java byte reader to an InputStream

Tags: java, byte, arrays, inputstream

Consider a generic **byte reader** implementing the following simple API to read an unspecified number of bytes from a data structure that is otherwise inaccessible:

```
public interface ByteReader
{
    public byte[] read() throws IOException; // Returns null only at EOF
}
```

How could the above be efficiently converted to a standard [Java InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), so that an application using all methods defined by the `InputStream` class, works as expected?

A simple solution would be subclassing `InputStream` to

1. Call the `read()` method of the `ByteReader` as much as needed by the `read(...)` methods of the `InputStream`
2. Buffer the bytes retrieved in a byte[] array
3. Return part of the byte array as expected, e.g., 1 byte at a time whenever the `InputStream read()` method is called.

However, this requires more work to be efficient (e.g., for avoiding multiple byte array allocations). Also, for the application to scale to large input sizes, reading everything into memory and then processing is not an option.

Any ideas or open source implementations that could be used?

Comment: Checked the [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) source code. I think it uses similar ideas and perhaps you can extend it to read from your data structure

Comment: Yes it does and I have checked it before writing the question. Essentially a function like fill() is needed, but it seems too complicated in the ByteArrayInputStream implementation, so I was wondering whether there is something simpler.

Comment: @PNS You can use `Arrays.fill()` on the underlying array of a `ByteInputStream`.

Comment: That is good only for setting one single value to multiple array positions. :-)

Comment: It seems that you have already thought of any alternatives offered to you in the answers, so I believe if you provide more explanations about your structures, where the bytes are coming from etc maybe someone comes up with a better idea. Also your interface seems that does not allow to specify how many bytes to attempt to return. Is that correct? Is there any way to estimate the length of the returned bytes?

Comment: This is a real use case that does not allow other types of access to the data, or knowing how many bytes will be read before calling the read() method of the byte reader.

Comment: I should point out that since `ByteReader` determines its own return buffer size, it is entirely up to the implementation to determine how many bytes to read at once. Therefore, you will have precisely the same number of `read` calls to consume the entire source no matter how many other layers of buffering you have on top of it. Buffering provides a performance gain when reading larger blocks of data at once produces less overhead, but you have zero control over whether or not you read a larger block of data, therefore buffering on top is pointless. You can't reduce the number of reads here.

Comment: No you can't, but that was not the main subject of the question. The ByteReader has to be converted to an InputStream first, before examining efficiency.

Comment: Sorry. The nature of your original question wandered in my mind over time after all that discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create multiple `ByteArrayInputStream` instances around the returned arrays and use them in a stream that provides for concatenation. You could for instance use [`SequenceInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html#SequenceInputStream%28java.util.Enumeration%29) for this.

Trick is to implement a `Enumeration<ByteArrayInputStream>` that is can use the `ByteReader` class.

EDIT: I've implemented this answer, but it is probably better to create your own `InputStream` instance instead. Unfortunately, this solution does not let you handle `IOException` gracefully.

---

```
final Enumeration<ByteArrayInputStream> basEnum = new Enumeration<ByteArrayInputStream>() {

    ByteArrayInputStream baos;
    boolean ended;

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        if (ended) {
            return false;
        }

        if (baos == null) {
            getNextBA();
            if (ended) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteArrayInputStream nextElement() {
        if (ended) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        if (baos.available() != 0) {
            return baos;
        }

        getNextBA();
        return baos;
    }

    private void getNextBA() {

        byte[] next;
        try {
            next = byteReader.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Issues reading byte arrays");
        }
        if (next == null) {
            ended = true;
            return;
        }
        this.baos = new ByteArrayInputStream(next);
    }
};

SequenceInputStream sis = new SequenceInputStream(basEnum);
```

Comment: I am aware of the SequenceInputStream but using a ByteArrayInputStream would be neither efficient, nor synchronous. What is needed is invoking the ByteReader read() method only if there are not enough byte retrieved and buffered already to satisfy the demand of the InputStream read(...) methods.

Comment: Is `new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(...))` not sufficient?

Comment: Nope, see my comments to your answer.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the implementation, but it is not efficient. Imagine having to call ByteReader.read() thousands or millions of times on a big file...

Comment: What do you mean, not efficient? You supplied us with a single interface, which I used. It does not create any additional buffer. The only thing it creates is additional objects, which are small and can be garbage collected very easily. You ask us for help, but you think you have enough knowledge to immediately judge any submissions.

Comment: I said thanks and gave you +1, which is the maximum reward for any help provided in this site. You can argue that I am wrong in a comment and that is fine, but I was replying to you (not the community/"us"), without forfeiting my right to express my opinion. So, there is no reason to get offended. On the subject, as per my previous comment: what would you do if the read() returned the bytes of a line, when processing a file with millions of lines, or more?

Comment: It is not that I'm offended, it's that you seem to condemn a solution for not being efficient without giving any specifics why you would deem it inefficient. I would generate my own `InputStream` implementation. You have got a proprietary interface, which is not going to be directly supported by any open source library. It's best to create a minimal implementation that directly returns bytes of the underlying buffer. It is of course best to support the `int read(byte[] buf, int off, int len)` directly for performance reasons.

Comment: But I did provide specifics from the very start: millions of calls to the read() method. Yes, it does seem that implementing the InputStream read(...) methods will be necessary.

Comment: Yes, but you don't say *why* this solution would be inefficient. Are you sure it is?

Comment: Well, I am not very comfortable with the idea of a few million ByteArrayInputStream objects floating around. Also, your code will cause an OutOfMemoryException for any file larger than a few GB, since you only stop when the ByteReader reports a null value, i.e. at EOF. If reading everything into memory was an option, you could just save the byte arrays.

Comment: @PNS: Your original interface is the source of the inefficiency. It is a poor design choice to not allow callers to provide reusable buffers or specify the number of bytes. If a class that implements `ByteReader` cannot read more than one byte at a time, e.g., it must create a new 1-element array for source byte. Conversely, even if the caller knows how much memory it wants to set aside for a data source, it has no choice but to let the data source allocate its own buffers. Perhaps a `ByteReader` reads, say, an entire file at once. If the file is 20GB, there's no way to specify the block size.

Comment: The interface just describes the behavior of a very popular third-party library, as I already explained and it is not a poor design at all. Ignore the use case if you don't believe it and say that it is a programming interview question. Would you insist in convincing the interviewer that they shouldn't have dared to ask, or would you try to find a solution? Thanks anyway! :-)

Comment: Assuming that your answer has always been as shown now, I must have overlooked the reuse of the ByteArrayInputStream, in the middle of a ton of things. You are right, your solution is quite elegant. I have implemented another one reusing arrays meanwhile, but would accept yours, too. Insulting comments aside, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, by your use of "convert", that a replacement is acceptable.

The easiest way to do this is to just use a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html), which already provides all the features you are looking for (but must wrap an existing array), or to use any of the other already provided `InputStream` for reading data from various sources.

It seems like you may be running the risk of reinventing wheels here. If possible, I would consider scrapping your `ByteReader` interface entirely, and instead going with one of these options:

1. Replace with `ByteInputStream`.
2. Use the various other `InputStream` classes (depending on the source of the data).
3. Extend `InputStream` with your custom implementation.

I'd stick to the existing `InputStream` class everywhere. I have no idea how your code is structured but you could, for example, add a `getInputStream()` method to your current data sources, and have them return an appropriate already-existing `InputStream` (or a custom subclass if necessary).

By the way, I recommend avoiding the term `Reader` in your own IO classes, as `Reader` is already heavily used in the Java SDK to indicate stream readers that operate on encoded character data (as opposed to `InputStream` which generally operates on raw byte data).

Comment: Where is your byte data originally coming from? Is `new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(...))` not sufficient?

Comment: There is no raw data access in my use case, hence the ByteReader interface described.

Comment: It would be helpful to know where the data was coming from. Can any of the data sources *not* be replaced by existing `InputStream` subclasses?

Comment: Yes, that is the assumption, data access is provided only via the ByteReader. But even if it did not, the question I posed is still valid and an interesting use case.

Comment: Valid, sure. Interesting, arguably, as the Java SDK has most if not all of that functionality built in. In any case, given that you want to keep `ByteReader` -- the correct answer is to create a subclass of `InputStream` that can wrap one of your `ByteReader`s *directly* (no buffering), and then wrap it with a `BufferedInputStream`. The `BufferedInputStream` has efficient buffering logic, so if you give `InputStream`-style raw access to your `ByteReader`, it will fit in anywhere an `InputStream` is required. I suggest wrapping because your `ByteReader` is an interface, not a class.

Comment: Check out the `InputStream` class documentation; it is straightforward to subclass, and it will be very easy to create one that operates on your `ByteReader`. (Edit: When I say arguably interesting, I mean to say that the use of `ByteReader` to begin with indicates a rather glaring design flaw rooted in a lack of understanding of available classes -- either an `InputStream` should have been used from the start, or an interface that simply provided `public InputStream getInputStream()`, thus allowing for custom source-specific implementations to be provided. That said, it is what it is.)

Comment: In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if most (if not all) of the `ByteReader` classes in this application use an `InputStream` as the data source anyways. I will post some example code of a wrapper later tonight, but you should be able to nail it in the mean time.

Comment: There is no design flaw. I can give you tons of examples of the simplified scenario I presented. The whole point is how to keep calling read() and buffering the data as necessary, with minimal resort to System.arraycopy() or Arrays.copyOf() or similarly expensive operations. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Tons of examples of poor design. :)

Comment: LOL Maybe, but there are tons of other examples that are fine design, having, for instance, to use closed source libraries that need to interoperate, in the way I already described.

Comment: You have enough information to create an `InputStream` wrapper on your own. I've decided not to do it for you. The implementation is very basic. All you need to override is `int read() throws IOException`. Logic is as follows: If we're at end of current buffer, read next block from ByteReader and reset buffer position. Return byte at current position and advance. You may further optimize by overriding the `read(...)` methods that take buffers and lengths. You cannot buffer without copying data and your only hope for efficiency here is that the individual `ByteReader` implementations are sane.

Comment: There was no need or assumption that you would write the code for me. Overriding the InputStream read(...) methods is the obvious solution and your approach is correct. I preferred to override the read(byte[]) method and reuse the buffers. Again, thanks for all the help. :-)

Comment: See my comment on your question. One consequence of the `ByteReader`s interface is that no matter how many layers of buffering you add on top, you will never be able to change the total number of `read` calls it takes to consume a stream. So, honestly, your best bet in terms of efficiency is to simply use `ByteReader` directly with nothing on top; the fact that it determines its own buffer size prevents all further buffering optimizations. I apologize for not spotting that earlier.

Comment: +1 and no need for apologies, of course. Again, thanks for your time. :-)